# How to change calender date to date using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Using moment().calendar(referenceTeime); I am able to get the relative days such as Today, Tomorrow, Yesterday etc. Now my requirement is to convert otherway from Today, Tomorrow etc to get the date value. Is it possible in moment.js? or Can somebody help me with shortcut to do using moment.js?

Answer (score 0):

No it's impossible to go from a calendar string (like Today at 8:45 AM) to a moment. Or, technically, you could build the pieces of the moment yourself but it'd likely not be worth it.

If you really need to do it this way take a look at: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/
That gives you a look at how the calendar strings work internally. But there aren't any moment methods that do it for you.

The easier way to do this is to always store the underlying type when you convert to calendar time. It's one of two things: a moment or a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

So an example:

```
var dur = moment.duration(2, 'days');
moment().add(dur).calendar(); // Tomorrow at 8:59 AM
moment().clone().add(dur).calendar(); // Same thing but preserves the moment.
```